# How to use switch to solve conditional problem

Tags: r

I have a data frame customer which contains two variable ,

**1)** gender

**2)** totalcharges

I want to check gender in 6th cell of "gender" column and want to give discount from total charges on the basis of gender.If it is Male the discount rate is 20% and if it is female then the discount rate is 50%.

can i do this by using switch function. any help would be appreciated.

i have used below mentioned code ;

```
x=switch(customer[c(6),"gender"],"Male","Female") %>%
  ifelse(gender == 'Female',
         MonthlyCharges * 0.5,
         MonthlyCharges * 0.2)
```

error i am getting is mentioned below

> Error in ifelse(., gender == "Female", MonthlyCharges * 0.5,
>   MonthlyCharges *  :    unused argument (MonthlyCharges * 0.2) In
>   addition: Warning message: In switch(customer[c(6), "gender"], "Male",
>   "Female") :   EXPR is a "factor", treated as integer.  Consider using
>   'switch(as.character( * ), ...)' instead.

Comment: For your use case (only 2 options) it makes more sense to use `if` and `else`. Is there a specific reason you want to use `switch`?

Comment: thanks for the reply. i got an assignment where i have to solve the problem by using switch

Comment: Could you post your (sample) data? You can post the output of `dput(customer)` for that.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
for(cellIndex in 1:length(customerchurn$gender)) {
  if(cellIndex==6) {
    result<-switch(customerchurn$gender[cellIndex], 
                   "Male"=customerchurn$MonthlyCharges[cellIndex]*.2,
                   "Female"=customerchurn$MonthlyCharges[cellIndex]*.5)
    break
  }
}
print(result)
```